# Will the complete() in first subscribe wait if I multiple subscribe inside subscribe?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have a multiple data to initialize in my web so I created a multiple subscribe.

My question is will the first subscribe wait to finish all the subscribe inside until it goes to complete() when there is no error found?

This is example

```
myFirstService.subscribe(
    data =>{
        mySecondService.subscribe(
            data =>{
                codes
            }
        )
    },
    error =>{},
    () => {}        <---------- will this () wait for the second service to finish?   
)
```

Comment: This is not a good approach to write your code. Use `switchMap` or `mergeMap` to call dependent service calls.

Comment: use mergeMap because it is best used when you wish to flatten an inner observable but want to manually control the number of inner subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the switchMap and mergeMap.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to wait for the second observable to finish, you'll need to handle logic in there.

Example:

```
   myFirstService.subscribe(
        data =>{
            mySecondService.subscribe(
                data =>{
                    codes
                },
               () => { // do stuff after second observable finishes }
            )
        },
        error =>{},
        () => {}        <---------- this will not wait for the second observable, only for the first   
    )
```

Comment: Please dont do it like this. Like suggested in the comments you should use an operator like `mergeMap/flatMap`, `concatMap` or `switchMap`.

Comment: I have 3 to 4 subscription in my module. I think it will become complicated.

Comment: By all means, use any of the `xMap` rxjs methods that fit your case. For the code shown, `mergeMap` is definitely the better approach. However this doesn't mean that it's a bad approach, espescially if you need to execute code after specific observables and refactor the `param` and `complete` bodies of the observables into new methods.